# Number of maximum consecutive heads

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Consider an iid. sequence of $p=1/2$ Bernoulli distributed random variables $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. We let $X=1$ be called 'heads' and $X=0$ be called 'tails'. Furthermore, for $X_n=1$ let $l_n=\max\{m\ge 0\colon X_i=1, n-(m-1)\le i \le n\}$ be the maximum number of consecutive heads at time $n$. For $X_n=-1$ set $l_n=0$.

Now I want to prove that $P(l_n\ge k)=2^{-k}$ and also want to determine for $L_n:=\max_{1\le m\le n}l_m$ the probability $P(L_n\ge j)$.

The first one should not be too hard, but I have problems obtaining the right result.

Comment: The probability to have $m-1$ times $X=1$ and a single time $X=-1$ is $m2^{-m}$, since there are $m$ different slots where the $-1$ can be.

Comment: @joriki No, the -1 has to be at the slot adjacent to the first +1 of the chain, otherwise the maximum would be larger, e.g. $X_1,X_2,..., -1,1,1,1,,1,1$. Do I make a mistake or you?

Comment: I think we both made a mistake in communicating :-) I'd add "then" before "a single time" to make clear that that's what you mean. Anyway, yes, in that case a single such run has probability $2^{-k}$, but how do you conclude from that that that's also the probability for $k$ to be the maximum? You say you "rewrite" $l_n$ to "free ourselves from the maximum"; but why can you rewrite it like that? (Also, your notation is unclear at that point; $-l_n$ was originally a number and now it's rewritten as a set?)

Comment: @joriki I made a typo in my question; this is corrected now. I need $m$ times the value $X=1$ and one time the value $X=-1$ from which I can conclude that the chain of successive +1's must end. That these +1's are next to each other is guaranteed by requiring $n-(m-1)\le i\le n$ in the defintion of $l_n$. Note that $l_n$ never was a value, but a random variable, this has not changed after rewriting. $l_n$ is simply a function of the $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: I understand that $l_n$ is a random variable. But you introduced it as an integer-valued random variable, and then you rewrite it as a set. If that's not what you intended, then something is wrong with your notation (in the line that starts in bold with "My attempt:"). I don't see how what you write there can be interpreted as a (random) number.

Comment: @joriki You are correct, this was another typo. I forgot to set $X_i=1$. I think I could make progress though. I did not incorporate the information that the $m$ +1's have to be at a specific location. They have to be exactly at the end of the chain. Let me know if anything is still unclear!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see how the $1$ has changed anything. $l_n$ is still being defined as a set in that line. Perhaps you're used to some notation that I'm not aware of and originally didn't see fit to explain it; but it's pretty likely that if I don't know it, there will be others who don't know it either, so I think you'd be well advised to spell out what you mean by that notation, if not a set.

Comment: @joriki I think I will delete my attempt and take the time for a new one. You are right, this does not formally make sense. I think I overexposed myself to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k>n$ the first probability is obviously $0$ and for $k\le n$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(l_n\ge k)=\mathsf{P}(X_n=1,X_{n-1}=1,\ldots, X_{n-k+1}=1)=2^{-k}
$$
by independence. As for the second probability, $L_n$ is the length of the longest run of heads in $n$ trials. Its distribution can be calculated recursively, that is
$$
\mathsf{P}(L_n\ge k)=1-2^{-n}S_n(k-1),
$$
where $S_n(j)$ is the number of sequences of length $n$ in which the longest run of heads does not exceed $j$ and is given by
$$
S_n(k)=\cases{\sum_{i=0}^k S_{n-i-1}(k), & $k<n$, \\ 2^n, & $k\ge n$.}
$$